# БД Android SQLite как проверить существование записи с определённым значением определённого столбца?

Tags: android, sql

Таблица состоит из id , номером и ФИО. Как сделать, чтобы при добавление в таблицу элемента с уже существующим номером обновлять старый элемент, а не добавлять новый. Как сделать проверку на наличие элемента с таким номером?

Comment: гуглите `sql select where`. Потом `sql update`

Answer (score 1):

В SQLite нет отдельного класса для хранения boolean. Вместо этого булевы значения можно хранить в целых числах (`integer`) `0` как `false` и `1` как `true`.

> Как сделать проверку на наличие элемента с таким номером?

```
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM Таблица
    WHERE Номер = 42
    LIMIT 1);
```

Оператор [EXISTS](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op) в SQL возвращает 1, если внутренний SELECT вернул хотя бы 1 столбец, и 0 в противном случае.

Для повышения производительности добавьте индекс для столбца `Номер`.

---

> Как сделать, чтобы при добавление в таблицу элемента с уже существующим номером обновлять старый элемент, а не добавлять новый?

Согласно официальной документации SQLite3 невозможно использовать `ON CONFLICT UPDATE`, только `REPLACE`. В случае дублирующегося значения уникального поля старая запись будет удалена, а новая вставлена `DELETE -> INSERT (новые значения)`.

1. Сделайте столбец `Номер` уникальным:

   ```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Index_номер
   ON Таблица (Номер)
   ON CONFLICT REPLACE;
   ```

   Можно также объявить его уникальным сразу при создании таблицы:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Таблица (
       id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
       Номер INTEGER NOT NULL,
       ФИО TEXT NOT NULL,
       UNIQUE (Номер) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
   )
   ```
2. Используйте [INSERT OR REPLACE](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)

   ...

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста,как изменить этот метод?Чтобы если в таблицу нет элемента с таким number возвращался false и иначе true?
public boolean Null(int number) {
          boolean check=true;
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
                        COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER, COLUMN_BUTTON_WIDTH }, COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(number) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor!=null)
            check=false;
        

            return check;

    }

Comment: @Mihailenko этот комментарий похож на самостоятельный вопрос. Поэтому [задайте новый вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) - и кто-нибудь ответит. Можете сослаться в нём на этот вопрос, если считаете необходимым. Комментарии обычно используют, чтобы получить пояснения по содержанию поста, уточнить вопрос или ответ. Рекомендую ознакомиться с [правилами сайта](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Mihailenko [Checking if a column exists in an application database in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15494674/1429387)